# I get the wrong radiobutton value returned , why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

This returns the value of the previous selected radio button value, why ?

```
<script>

    $("#ptmodel label").click(function () {

 var selected = $("input[name=in_pt_model]:checked").val(); 
 var selecteddataString = 'in_pt_model='+ selected;
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "badkamer_sets.php",
    data: selecteddataString,
    success: function(selected){
            $("#ptsize_check").html(selected);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: The HTML for your radio buttons may be helpful, too.

Comment: Without the `HTML` this question is a no-go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess `#ptmodel label` is the label associated with the `input[name=in_pt_model]`.

Instead of using the click event of the label (assosicated with input[name=in_pt_model]").) handle the change event of input[name=in_pt_model]").

Try this:

```
<script>
    $("#ptmodel input[name=in_pt_model]").change(function () {
     var selected = $(this).val(); 
     var selecteddataString = 'in_pt_model='+ selected;
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "badkamer_sets.php",
            data: selecteddataString,
            success: function(selected){
                                    $("#ptsize_check").html(selected);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My gut tells me that the underlying issue here is that the jquery onclick event you are attaching to the radio button is firing before the DOM handles the click event, meaning the radio button has not actually been clicked yet, so when you check the .val() it still reports the old value. Changing the event from click to change should fix this.

Comment: THANX :D , I should have known ;).

Answer (score 0):

My gut tells me that the underlying issue here is that the jquery onclick event you are attaching to the radio button is firing before the DOM handles the click event, meaning the radio button has not actually been clicked yet, so when you check the .val() it still reports the old value. Changing the event from click to change should fix this. –